# How to migrate jobs from Jenkins1 to Jenkins2 without access to Jenkins sever

Tags: jenkins

How to migrate jobs from Jenkins1 to Jenkins2 without access to Jenkins sever and with no plugins? Using shared library can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create jobs, you can create a new one which archives (e. g. with tar) and publishes the archive as an artifact.

If you can't create jobs, you probably can modify existing one.

If you controls VCS repository, you could hijack build process to create archive and send/upload it somewhere :)